# Método de array não disponível? Erro "sort is not a function" ao aplicá-lo em NodeList

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var letterDivs = gameBox.getElementsByClassName("wordBox")[0].childNodes;

console.log(letterDivs); //=> NodeList[...]

// Dá erro: `sort is not a function`:
letterDivs.sort((a, b) => {
  a.style.order > b.style.order ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Eis o que o `console.log(letterDivs)` me retorna:

[image: O que console.log(letterDivs) retorna]

Como é um array estou a tentar usar o método `sort` mas dá erro. Por quê? Como solucionar este problema? O objetivo é ordenar as letras pela ordem da propriedade de estilos `order`.

Também não funciona com outros métodos "comuns" de arrays, como `map` e `filter`. Por quê?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você não está trabalhando com um [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), mas sim com um [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Métodos como o `getElementsByClassName` ou o `querySelectorAll` não retornam um array, mas sim uma coleção de elementos DOM. Essa coleção é chamada `NodeList` e é um objeto diferente de `Array` (e portanto não implementa todos os métodos de "arrays convencionais", como o `sort`, `filter`, `map`, etc).

Nesse sentido, como o método `sort` é implementado no protótipo do `Array`, uma opção é converter o seu `NodeList` para um array antes de utilizá-lo. Abaixo mostro algumas opções para isso.

---

Como `NodeList` implementa o protocolo de iteração da linguagem, você pode utilizar o operador de espalhamento para convertê-lo em um `Array`:

```
[...letterDivs].sort((a, b) => /* ... */);
```

No exemplo acima, `[...letterDivs]` é uma expressão que avalia para um array. Por isso podemos utilizar `sort` depois.

Uma outra opção é utilizar o `Array.from`, que também retorna um array:

```
Array.from(letterDivs).sort((a, b) => /* ... */);
```

Uma observação é que os dois formatos acima retornam um array. Então, a expressão não retorna um `NodeList`, mas sim um `Array`.

---

Poderia se pensar em utilizar `Function.prototype.call` ou `Function.prototype.apply`, mas como o método `Array.prototype.sort` não copia o `this` (que geralmente é um array) original, as modificações são feitas no próprio valor passado como *argumento* `this`.

Assim, se você utilizar uma `NodeList` como `this` do `sort`, pode acabar recebendo um erro como "Failed to set an indexed property". *Pode* acabar modificando o DOM desintencionalmente também, já que `NodeList` é uma "lista viva".

Comment: Mas quando eu faço um console.log das letterDivs depois do sort retorna-me um nodelist. PorquÊ?

Comment: Hmm, é verdade. Editei a resposta. :)

Answer (score 4):

Não é uma array, é uma NodeList do DOM. Você pode usar o seguinte:

```
Array.prototype.sort.call(letterDivs, (a, b) => ...)
```